# Postgis -> Geoserver -> GeoJson -> Mapbox gl js

Tags: mapbox, postgis, geojson, geoserver, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to solve an issue with mt mapbox-gl-js implementation.
The data I would like to display is stored in postgis. I understand that direct postgis->mapbox-gl-js is not possible and I have to go via a geo server.

I installed geo server and get a geojson stream when I access: `http://192.168.2.7:8081/geoserver/DCSIdefix/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=DCSIdefix:units&maxFeatures=500&outputFormat=application/json`

I then added this as URL to the mapbox-gl-js:

```
var url = 'http://192.168.2.7:8081/geoserver/DCSIdefix/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=DCSIdefix:units&maxFeatures=500&outputFormat=application/json';

map.addSource('dcs', { type: 'geojson', data: URL });
```

after which I create the layer to display the data on the map.

Issue:

- I can see the query arriving at the geoserver and the geojson is
  generated but the data is not displayed on the map
- if I replace the direct geoserver URL with a file on the same server instead, generated from the same
  URL (quick and dirty wget batch file which overwrites the geojson file every 5 seconds) and use the file instead of the URL, it works perfectly so the geojson data is fine just the script is
  somehow not able to take the data (maybe it does not wait for the full stream to arrive?).

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks !

Comment: your variable names don't match url is not the same as URL

Comment: Found any solution?